# Percentages on population

Tags: percentages

The population of london is 12,60000. Of this 2/3rd are men and they are to marry women of London only. If 40% of men were married, find the % of unmarried women?

Answer (score 1):

2/3 men of $1260000$ is  $2/3*1260000=840000$

1/3 women of $1260000$ is $1/3*1260000=420000$

$420000\cdot40/840000= 0.2$ or $20\%$

Answer (score 0):

2/3 of 12,600,000 is the same as 2/3 * 12,600,000 = 8,400,000 men. Based on your last question, I think you can figure out the rest!

Comment: Try to figure out the rest and post your idea here. If it's wrong, I'll fix it.

Comment: till there even i got but i did get after that so posted

Comment: Are you saying you solved it?

Comment: yes but i didnt get a right answer.

Comment: Post your attempt. I think that MSE would appreciate your question more if you post your process to prove that you made a good attempt at it. Also, then we can show you where you went wrong and fix it.